# Firebase Storage keeps replacing image when uploading

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload 2 images at once and get the DownloadURL to go to the Firebase Database but the second Image function keeps replacing the first one so when I click on the downloadURL for either the first or second it will only grab the second Image. This is my code.

```
@IBAction func upload(_ sender: Any) {


    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image.png")
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView1.image!){
    storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in



        let storageRef2 = Storage.storage().reference().child("images2/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image2.png")
        if let uploadData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView2.image!){
        storageRef2.putData(uploadData2, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in



                if error != nil {
                        print("error")
                        return

                    } else {
                        let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                        let downloadURL2 = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                        self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text, "Subtitle": self.subtitleText.text, "Article": self.articleText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text, "Tags": self.tagsText.text, "PostType": self.postType.text, "PostStyle": self.postStyle.text, "PostSize": self.postSize.text, "Download URL": (downloadURL), "Download URL 2": (downloadURL2)])

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse your link is the same, your downloadURL and downloadURL2 is referring to the same metadata?.downloadURL?.absoluteString. Try this:

```
@IBAction func upload(_ sender: Any) {
checkExist(url: inserttheurlhere){ succes in
if succes{
//image exist
//continue your work here when the picture exist
}else{
//error downloading, not exist or other failure
//continue your work here when no exist
}

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("images/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image.png")
    if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView1.image!){
    storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in



        let storageRef2 = Storage.storage().reference().child("images2/\(NSUUID().uuidString)/image2.png")
        if let uploadData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myImageView2.image!){
        storageRef2.putData(uploadData2, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadataSecond, error) in



                if error != nil {
                        print("error")
                        return

                    } else {
                        let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                        let downloadURL2 = metadataSecond?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                        self.ref?.child("Posts").childByAutoId().setValue(["Title": self.titleText.text, "Subtitle": self.subtitleText.text, "Article": self.articleText.text, "Author": self.authorText.text, "Date": self.dateText.text, "Tags": self.tagsText.text, "PostType": self.postType.text, "PostStyle": self.postStyle.text, "PostSize": self.postSize.text, "Download URL": (downloadURL), "Download URL 2": (downloadURL2)])

            }

func checkExist(url: String, completionHandler:@escaping (Bool) -> ()){
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child(url)
        if let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.theuiview.image!){
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
if error == nil && metadata != nil{
completionHandler(true)
}else{
completionHandler(false)
}
})
}
```

Comment: It worked! Also, do you know how to only upload the second Image if it's there and only upload the first? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Riccardo I updated the code in which you can enter any url which the function checkExist will look for. If data exist and errors are nil, the function completes 'true' else 'false' and you can continue your work where I said you can :). Please accept the answer for your question

Answer (score 2):

As shown above you just need to include differnt URL for each and every image.
Eg

` // Create a timestamp as filename
    const filename = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

```
// Create a reference to 'images/todays-date.jpg'
this.storRef=firebase.storage().ref();
const imageRef = this.storRef.child(`images/${filename}.jpg`);`
```

Here cause of the **filename** it will change every time you uploading.try this kind of thing.problem is in the same URL providing.